# Random "prod" string value in console when trying to .value

Tags: javascript, html, click, listener

I have grabbed a value from an in input box many times before, but don’t know whats going on. I want to grab the value only of what I type inside the input box after clicking the plus button, but the console keeps logging “prod”. Is anyone else seeing this or is there something wrong with my bowser? ( or maybe code??)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <input type="text">
  <button id="add-btn">+</button>

  <h1>List</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <p>Coffee</p><button id="remove-btn">-</button>
    </li>
  </ol>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li button {
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

JS

```
let userInput = document.querySelector('input')
let inputValue = userInput.value

let addItemBtn = document.getElementById('add-btn')

let newLi = "Hi, Im Li"

addItemBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target === addItemBtn) {
    console.log("inputValue: ", inputValue);    
  }

})
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting "prod" but you're grabbing the value from the input before you've clicked the button so it will always be an empty string. Get rid of the second line of JS and change `console.log("inputValue: ", inputValue);` to `console.log("inputValue: ", userInput.value);`. You also don't need the `if (event.target === addItemBtn) {` condition as the listener is attached to the button so you don't really need that check.

Comment: The value is going to be whatever the value is then the page renders.  `let inputValue = userInput.value` does not keep updating as the user changes the value.

Comment: ok I changed it around to how you mentioned but am still getting in the console inputValue: "prod". Any idea of what is going on? if its browser issue with chrome what should I do to fix?

Comment: **querySelector** grabs the FIRST matching element, that means you have another input ABOVE the code that you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Move your logic to *inside* the event handler

```js
const addItemBtn = document.getElementById('add-btn');

addItemBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target === addItemBtn) {
  
    let userInputValue = document.querySelector('input').value;  
    console.log("inputValue: ", userInputValue);    

  }

});
```

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li button {
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" />
 <button id="add-btn">+</button>

 <h1>List</h1>
 <ol>
    <li>
      <p>Coffee</p><button id="remove-btn">-</button>
    </li>
 </ol>
```

Comment: Hi code_monk. Unfortunately I still get a value of "prod" inside the console. This has to be a browser issue vs incorrect placement right? I want to note that I don't have any dependencies attached. only a html, css, and js file and nothing else. I also tried updating chrome to see if that would make a difference but it did not. 

I did however try working on an incognito browser instead and that DOES work. but I never had to do that before. I want to do it without incognito mode.